# How to use UI Automator classes in maven project in eclipse?

Tags: appium, appium-android

I'm new to android testing with UIAutomator 2, and I want to use the class UIScrollable but this class is inside android.support package. I'm unable to find any dependency which can be added to pom for importing the class.

Comment: How do you mean "use the class?"  In what manner?  Are you using Appium webdrivers?  Show us your code, what you've tried, etc.

Comment: Yes, I'm using appium, but  uiautomator and other android classes need to be imported. By what way can I import them in my appium backed tests.

Answer (score 1):

Actually its much simpler.

You don't have to add any dependencies in your project as its build-in in appium dependency, just set `automationName` capability to `UiAutomator2` and appium will use UiAutomator2 server + client to run your tests.

```
    driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector())
 .scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text(\"Radio Group\"));"));
```

Basically same way it was for default UiAutomator.